# What is the best (most efficient or conventional) way to control "MenuItem"s in Android's "ActionBar"?

Tags: android, android-menu

When controlling a MenuItem, I have been doing this:

```
Menu menu;

(...)

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    return true;
}

(...)

public void handleSearch(View view) {
    Button button = (Button) view;
    if(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).isVisible()) {
        button.setText(R.string.button_search_show);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);
    } else {
        button.setText(R.string.button_search_hide);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

"this" being referencing the menu created in onCreateOptionsMenu with a Menu that any method in the class can use. The handleSearch method controls MenuItems by using findItem twice. This doesn't feel very conventional or efficient (a very scientific observation, I might add). Is there a more conventional or efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save MenuItem in a variable instead of using findItem twice.

```
MenuItem myMenuitem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method that handles actionBar's menu itself.

Try this:

```
@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
        super.onBackPressed();
        return (true);

    case R.id.menu_home:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return (true);

     }

    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
 }
```

Comment: I'm not responding to a click or a selection. I'm trying to control the action itself.

Comment: Ooops, you can save MenuItem in a variable instead of using findItem twice.

Comment: If you put that in an answer, I'll mark it as the answer to this question.